# what is difference between setForeground and setForegroundAsync in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-notifications, android-workmanager

Hey I am working in **WorkManager**. My code is running in **android 11** and below . I want to support WorkManager for **sdk 31(android 12)**. I am reading doc and it confused for my scenario [Backwards compatibility and foreground services](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#backwards-compat). I am adding code please have a look and guide me is my code doing right?

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"
```

**NotificationWorker.kt**

```
class NotificationWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, workerParams),
    KoinComponent {

    private val notifications: Notifications by inject()

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        notifications.createNotification(NotificationType.REMINDER, null)
        TrackerHelper.setupNotificationWorker()
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**TrackerHelper.kt**

```
object TrackerHelper {

     fun setupNotificationWorker() {
           val delayDuration = getDelayMillis()
           val dailyWorkRequest = 
                OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>()
                   .setInitialDelay(delayDuration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                   .addTag(REMINDER_WORK_TAG)
                  .build()
          WorkManager.getInstance(Application.appContext).enqueue(dailyWorkRequest)
    }

    private fun getDelayMillis(): Long {
           val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance()
           val dueDate = getNotificationDueTime()
           if (dueDate.before(currentDate)) {
               dueDate.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24)
           }
           return dueDate.timeInMillis - currentDate.timeInMillis
    }
}
```

The above is perfectly working in **android 11** and **below version**. But It's not working in **android 12**. So I am reading in official doc [Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-kotlin) inside `doWork()` they are using `setForeground()` and in [Java](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-java) using `setForegroundAsync()`. So which is useful in my case. [CoroutineWorker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#coroutineworker) and what the use case of `getForegroundInfo()` this function and how to proper handle this not to throw error

[image]

I am totally confused what function need to be used in my case and please explain me which one is use when with example. Thanks in advance

I am getting this error in **android 12**

```
2022-01-10 12:00:00.333 9958-10168/com.example.app.dev E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=827b6cde-a3fe-42ab-89f3-92c88af95fd9, tags={ com.example.app.tracker.TrackerNotificationWorker, tracker_reminder_work } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.app.dev: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:311)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.app.dev: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
        at com.example.app.notifications.NotificationsNative.launchNotification(NotificationsNative.kt:67)
        at com.example.app.notifications.NotificationsNative.createTrackerReminderNotification(NotificationsNative.kt:35)
        at com.example.app.notifications.NotificationsNative.createNotification(NotificationsNative.kt:28)
        at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerNotificationWorker.doWork(TrackerNotificationWorker.kt:19)
        at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
            ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the error you get on Android 12?

Please, review Android 12 Foreground Services Restrictions: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines

Comment: @pfmaggi I added error in my question. Please have a look. Thanks